# Huge datasets operations issues on AWS

Tags: pandas, amazon-ec2, dask

I have 5 csv of files of approximately 20gb each.

I did all my code in order to transform and merge them with pandas on samples of 1 go each.

Now, I use my code on the real datasets on AWS EC2, and still with pandas.

My questions are:

1. I think it's useless to use a GPU for this problem? Am I wrong?
2. Should I use an other library than Pandas (like Dask?)
3. What kind of caracteristics should I choose for EC2 ? (Several CPUs, or only one? ...)
4. For the moment, my code does not give errors, but my final dataset has only 100 rows. Is the data too huge, so Pandas automatically ignore a lot of rows??

Thanks a lot

Here is an example of the kind of code I have to do on these huge datasets:

```
as_country = pd.merge(as_country, conventions_data, left_on='country', right_on = 'country_x', how = 'left')
as_country = as_country.dropna()
as_country = as_country.drop(columns=['countryname'])
as_country.enforce_date = as_country.enforce_date.astype(int)


as_country = as_country.drop(columns=['country_x', 'country_y','country_code','year'])
as_country['date_minus_enforcedate'] = as_country['date'] - as_country['enforce_date']
as_country['date_minus_enforcedate'] =  np.where((as_country.date_minus_enforcedate <= 0), -1, 1)
## AS_country will be just for one day and group by:

as_country = as_country.groupby(['as', 'country']).mean().reset_index()


as_country = as_country.drop(columns=['date', 'enforce_date'])
as_country_columns = list(as_country.columns)
as_country_columns.remove('as')
as_country_columns.remove('country')
as_country = as_country.pivot(index='as', columns='country', values=as_country_columns)
as_country = as_country.fillna(0)
```

Comment: Do you mind to share a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: I just added some code to show the kind of operations :-) 
merge, pivot, etc.

Comment: that is not a mcve. I don't any idea of how your dataframes are. Plus you should highlight your issue first. Pandas drops data only if  it's the user ask to do so.

Comment: I can't show this data on the internet. But all the datasets are standard csv files, with a dozen columns, but millions of rows (20 go per csv file, 6 files).

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this as an expanded comment.

1. *I think it's useless to use a GPU for this problem? Am I wrong?*

If it's a one-off computation yes. Otherwise have a look at [cudf](https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf) from [rapids.ai](https://rapids.ai/) or [blazingSQL](https://blazingdb.com).

2. *Should I use an other library than Pandas (like Dask?)*

If your computation run in memory you don't need Dask see [docs](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html)

3. *What kind of caracteristics should I choose for EC2 ? (Several CPUs, or only one? ...)*

I suggest you to estimate the maximum RAM usage and get a 10-20% more. Number of cores is somehow related (i.e. you can't have 1 core and 200GB of RAM)

4. *For the moment, my code does not give errors, but my final dataset has only 100 rows. Is the data too huge, so Pandas automatically ignore a lot of rows??*

For this problem, which should be your principal concern, you should check step-by-step your commands. It's weird to me that you first drop `as` and `country` columns and then you  use them to pivot.

Comment: Thanks for your help. For your fourth remark, that's normal that I do that, because as and country will be index and columns, while the rest will be values. 


I ran my code with sample of only few giga, and it worked perfectly, that's why I'm surprised it does not on the real data.

Comment: What do you mean by "run in memory" and "maximum RAM usage?". How can I have answers to these questions?

Comment: @nolw38 if in your computer you are not getting `Out of Memory` error then your computation run in memory. To, roughly, check your maximum RAM usage you can use `top` or task manager.